# ios/xcode: change title of bar button item

Tags: ios, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I want to change the title of a bar button (right navigation) from login to sign up depending on which the user checks.

Previously, I had this as a button in the VC and it worked with the following code:

```
[_submitButton setTitle:@"Sign Up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

However, now that I've deleted the button in the page and have given the bar button the name submitButton, I am getting the following error:

No visible @interface for 'UIBarButtonItem' declares the selector 'setTitleForState'

Does anyone know why this is not working?  Do I have to name uibarbutton something different than a regular button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIBarButtonItem` is not `UIButton`

Please check the following:

- option-click on `_submitButton`, you will see a popover with declaration and type.
- click on `UIBarButtonItem`, you will see the documentation.
- there is no method at all to set the title.
- look at the line *Inherits from:* on the top under the big class name.
- `UIBarButtonItem` is a subclass of `UIBarItem`
- click on `UIBarItem`
- There is a `title` property without further arguments, so it's

  ```
  _submitButton.title = @"Sign Up";
  ```

Reading the documentation is very important, it's impossible to remember all properties/methods of all classes but it's the first thing you should do if you get an error message like this.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm waiting for Objective C to become intuitive but it has not yet happened.  So these types of errors tend to flummox me.  Thanks for reminder to check docs!

Comment: The error message is pretty descriptive, though. `no selector` is *wrong method - check the documentation*

Comment: Ok.   I may have accepted answer to soon.  Method is throwing error when it gets to _submitButton.title = "@Sign Up";

Comment: OK, the error message says that `_submitButton` is not an `UIBarButtonItem` it's a `String`